# gapi.client.init failed: Not a valid origin for the client: http://localhost:4200 has not been whitelisted for client ID

Tags: angular, typescript, google-api

I am trying to call Gmail API from my Angular app, but for some reason I get this error:

[image]

I have been using my project setup in dev console for a long time.

I am making a call as defined in Gmail API documentation, https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/js adjusted for Angular:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

const API_KEY = '**************v4bXc58f61rA';
const CLIENT_ID = '***************dnioepu4c06kqk3ke72n.apps.googleusercontent.com';
const DISCOVERY_DOCS = ['https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/gmail/v1/rest', 'https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest'];
const SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly';

declare var gapi: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'my-app';

  constructor(private service: AppService) {
    console.log('AppComponent.constructor()');
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    gapi.load('client:auth2', this.initClient);
  }

  initClient() {
    gapi.client.init({
      apiKey: API_KEY,
      clientId: CLIENT_ID,
      discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
      scope: SCOPES
    }).then(() => { 
      console.log('gapi.client.init successful');
    }, (error) => {
      console.error('gapi.client.init failed: ', error.details);
    });
  }

}
```

All the required parameters listed in `gapi.client.init()` function are defined in my project.

`http://localhost:4200` is added to **Authorized JavaScript origins** and **Authorized redirect URIs**

I even added the **Google Analytics API** as was suggested in other threads (not sure why).

[image]

So the URL is whitelisted, **not sure why I still get the error**.

Answer (score 0):

Jeez, it was some caching issue :)

Everything was done correctly.

No need to add "Google Analytics API".

Just clear cache, using "Incognito" mode doesn't help, since cookies are not supported.